# How to return result from an async js function

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am writing a simple night watch test with selenium that test successful login and failed login. My test works fine but the result is not returning what i expected. Below is my test.

```
module.exports = {

    'Login Success': function(browser){
        var data = browser.globals;
        browser
            .url(data.launch_url)
            .login(data.token,function(result){
                console.log("The login is successful",result.value);
            })
            .verify.elementNotPresent('.errorfield')
            .verify.elementPresent('#header')
            .end();
    }
};
```

and my custom command login

```
exports.command = function(token, callback){
    const element = this.globals.login_element;
    callback = callback || function(){};

    this
        .waitForElementPresent(element.tokenInput, 5000)
        .verify.elementPresent(element.tokenInput)
        .setValue(element.tokenInput, token)
        .click(element.signinButton)
        .pause(1000)
        .execute(function(token) {
            return !!(document.getElementById(element.tokenInput));
        },[token],function(result){
            callback.call(this,result);
        });

    return this;
};
```

My test works fine . However, i am expecting

```
console.log("The login is successful",result.value);
```

to print a boolean value , that is true or false. Yet the result return some long selenium object that does not make sense at all. Please where do i go wrong ? from

```
.execute(function(token) {
                return !!(document.getElementById(element.tokenInput));
            }
```

I was expecting to have a boolean result return to my console as a result and definitely should. Any help would be appreciated.